# Weird behavior of $index in ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic framework and I have the following code:

**WORKS FINE:**

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChange()">
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="selected in instanceList">
        {{$index}}
        <div ng-if="currSlide==$index || !currSlide">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

**DOESN'T WORK:**

```
<ion-slide-box on-slide-changed="slideChange()">
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="selected in instanceList">
        <div ng-if="currSlide==$index || !currSlide">
             CONTENT
        </div>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

For those who are not familiar with Ionic, this function ensures me that `currSlide` is always updating its value and it's always the same value of `$index`:

```
$scope.slideChange = function() {
    $scope.currSlide = $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex();
};
```

*More details*: When I say that the second code doesn't work: the content of the first slide appears, but when I change slides, the content of the div doesn't appear. In the first code everything appears just fine (also the `$index` I am printing).

**CODEPEN:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mdsIr

Comment: Ever figure this out?  I'm seeing similar behavior with a slide box and ng-if

Answer (score 0):

The two-way data binding `{{}}` of `{{$index}}` has a `$watch` in the directive, so removing the {{}} removes a $watch that updates the slides.

Comment: What should I do for it to be watched without the two-way data binding?

Comment: You could do <div id="{{$index}}" ng-if="...">

Comment: Do you have a plnkr of the ionic slider? I've never used the ionic framework. May just ng-change to an element, or aet suggestion.

Comment: Putting the id didn't work, @aet. Here is a codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mdsIr

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that requires removing {{$index}}? I might be wrong, but it looks like `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.currentIndex()` requires  `$index` to be rendered on page. To work around that you would have to add UI for $index reference selection, then change business logic to suit.

Comment: I just don't want a number to appear on the screen, so I need to remove `{{$index}}`, but I use `$index` for the logic I'm doing.